# Can MongoDB query (A AND B) OR (C AND D) with any mix of text and structured clauses?

Tags: mongodb, search, boolean-logic

I'm developing a [search app](https://twitter.com/AndOrSearch/status/1519979302938361857) that allows users to combine arbitrary combinations of structured and unstructured clauses with Boolean logic in a graphical editor.

I have it working with an elasticsearch back-end but mongodb looks to be a no-go because of [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#restrictions):

> A query can specify, at most, one $text expression.

That doesn't fly for me. I'd need to support `(A OR B) AND (C OR D)` where any of these clauses could be a text query e.g both `A` and `D`.

Is there any work-around? I'm a mongo noobie so wanted to check before I write it off as a choice of back-end.

Comment: Mongo is not a search engine, so it's not the preferred solution for such a requirement, however they did launch "atlas search" which is works very similar to elasticsearch and also allows you to enjoy other MongoDB features. I recommend you give that a look.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/

Comment: Thanks, Tom. It looks like it runs as a separate mongot process, passing matching IDs to mongob. Even if it were possible to define hybrid structured+unstructured requests like my example I can't imagine it scaling well when executed with that approach.

Comment: It really depends how large your searches are, naturally these search engines are very efficient for focused searches and start paying in performance the larger the search and deeper the pagination.

Comment: The cost is more about the number of matches rather than clauses. My example query only has 4 clauses. Let's say we were searching for posts like mine: (tag:mongodb OR body:mongodb) AND (tag:boolean-logic or body:"boolean logic"). That's 4 clauses but the mongot process would have to stream back hundreds of thousands of doc ids for the 'body:mongodb' clause matches so the mongo process can narrow down to a handful based on ANDed criteria. It's always better to have 1 engine/process doing structured + unstructured clauses. I expect that's why mongo doesn't offer text + geo queries too.